# iOS Photos app and widget For You and Memories stuck on date from last month

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, photos, widgets

I use a Photos widget on my iPhone. It shows Featured Photos and Memories as chosen by iOS. The Photos widget *used* to switch through to new photos and memories frequently.

The widget is currently **stuck** on October 10th. (It's currently November 7th.) The widget just flips through the pictures:

- On this Day: October 10, 2022
- Jane Doe: Over the Years (my friend whose birthday is October 10th)

If I delete and/or re-add a new Photos Widget, of any size class, they are now always still displaying the photos for this October 10th date.

Also, if I open the Photos app, the "For You" tab shows these same memories. No new memories are being generated, for example, another friend's birthday that is today.

How can I trigger the Photos to get new data? Why is it stuck on a date from last month?

[image: Memories and Featured Photos widget]

> Featured
> Appreciate special moments through Memories and Featured Photos

Notes:

- I switched from an older iPhone to a iPhone 15 Pro on October 17th. This might have something to do with it, or not.
- I do NOT want to reset all Photos data, sign out of iCloud, or do anything else that is extremely destructive.